# How much overhead is created by calling methods from another class versus calling a method from the came class?

Tags: java

I recently learned that after a java program is compiled classes/methods are statically linked and method names don't have an impact during runtime.

My question is: How much overhead is created by calling methods from another class versus calling the method from the same class?

I have a Bounds class that is sort of my own version of a rectangle. I have another class that is basically an Entity that holds the drawing information. Currently I have a method in this Entity class that generates the current Bounds from the list of points in the class it self and returns the new bounds. However, I wanted to move this method into the Bounds class and just have it take the list of points as a parameter and then return the Bounds. I only want to move this method into the Bounds class to clean up the Entity class as I don't think this method should belong here. I would have to update my code in some method. My Entity class doesn't keep a bounds object as I have to update this bounds every method with the current Transformation Matrix and I don't want to generate this every frame when I only need it for mouse selection purposes. My guess is that the local method would be faster.

```
Bound b = getBounds(); // This would have to change to the below

Bound b = Bounds.getBounds(this.listOfPoints); // This is a List<Point>
```

Comment: Your program is so "critic" that you need to care about that?

Comment: If you're writing a program where this type of thing is important (almost never) you don't program in Java. Questions like this are almost completely meaningless in Java.

Comment: Not really, no. I just thought of the question and wanted to know if there was a performance impact is all. I don't see anything wrong with trying to find out the best practices for the future.

Comment: If by "compiled" you refer to the effects of JIT compilation inside the VM, then your assertion is likely correct, but subject to implementation details.  On the other hand, if you mean compiled to `.class` files then the assertion is incorrect -- method invocations are bound by name and signature at runtime.  I'm fairly certain this is true even for non-virtual methods (i.e. `private` and/or `static` ones), but it is necessarily true for virtual ones (i.e. all the others).

Comment: As far as the compiled thing goes, I asked a question a few days ago that about it method name sizes increased run time and I was told a few times that methods are statically linked and the byte code is something like invokeStatic b4(the method name)

Comment: The best practice is just to write code that's sensible, easy to read and easy to understand. If you really want to learn about performance of method calls, you should read about vtables and virtual methods. (But those are still not particularly relevant to Java because there is so much other stuff going on.) Basically you just shouldn't worry about the microscopic things you're asking about. Those don't impact performance at all in a Java program.

Comment: @AustinK., the class file format includes a string table wherein method signatures, among other things, are stored.  Strings in this table can be (and are, for some purposes) referenced by index.  That is not at all the same thing as static linking, however, and it does not follow that method name details have no runtime impact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java is an Object Oriented language. Which means that you as a programmer should write your code in such a way that methods are located where they belong (i.e. where it makes sense for them to be) In 99% of the cases the performance should not be at all a consideration. Java compiler and JVM have very powerful and smart performance optimizers. Rely on them to do their job and write your code in a way that it is self-explainable. That would save you tones of time when you or someone else will need to maintain/modify your code.